# babel-preset-es2016 requires a peer of babel-runtime but none was installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I realize that npm doesn't install peer dependencies anymore, but when I do the manual install, why do I still get the warning?

```
    ➜  npm install babel-runtime -g     
    /usr/local/lib
    └─┬ babel-runtime@6.6.1 
      └── core-js@2.2.1 

    ➜  npm install babel-preset-es2016 -g
    /usr/local/lib
    ├── babel-preset-es2016@6.0.8 
    └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-runtime@^6.6.1

npm WARN babel-preset-es2016@6.0.8 requires a peer of babel-runtime@^6.6.1 but none was installed.
```

**EDIT**

If I install locally (per suggestion below), I don't get the warning:

```
➜  test npm i babel-runtime@\^6.6.1
test@1.0.0 /home/jdifool/work/test
├── babel-preset-es2016@6.0.8 
├── babel-runtime@6.6.1 
└─┬ babelify@7.2.0
  └─┬ babel-core@6.7.4
    ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.7.4
    │ └── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    ├─┬ babel-generator@6.7.2
    │ └── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    ├─┬ babel-helpers@6.6.0
    │ └── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    ├─┬ babel-messages@6.7.2
    │ └── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    ├─┬ babel-register@6.7.2
    │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    │   └── core-js@1.2.6 
    ├── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    ├─┬ babel-template@6.7.0
    │ └── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.7.4
    │ └── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    ├─┬ babel-types@6.7.2
    │ └── babel-runtime@5.8.38 
    └─┬ babylon@6.7.0
      └── babel-runtime@5.8.38
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty verbose. Just install the required package

```
$ npm i babel-runtime@^6.6.1 -g
```

Install in the global scope because your preset is also in the global scope and try again.

**UPDATE** (by @JohnDifool):
It seems that the warning is only showing for a global install.

Comment: The caret can't be used (npm i babel-runtime@^6.6.1 -g
zsh: no matches found: babel-runtime@^6.6.1) and I already installed babel-runtime@6.6.1

Comment: My bad: I needed to escape with \^ on zsh. Still no luck because `npm i babel-runtime@^6.6.1 -g` stubbornly installs 6.6.1 (latest?). My npm -version is 3.8.3.

Comment: Can you try installing this package `babel-core`, as `npm i babel-core -g`. **Suggestion**: Why not move everything to an isolated folder?

Comment: babel-core@6.7.4  is already installed by babel-cli@6.6.5 & babel-preset-es2016@6.0.8. I could install inside an isolated folder, although if the problem happens globally, it will probably be the same locally.

Comment: I run 3 projects with a similar setup and they work fine!

Comment: I edited my question with you comment and suggestion. It seems that the warning is only showing for a global install. I'll stick with the non -g version then.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem, it was resolved by updating npm, clearing the npm cache, then running the `npm install` command again. However, there were issues along the way, as I shall detail.

## Updating npm

First, I tried to update npm using `npm update -g npm`, but that threw an error:

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /private/var/folders/_n/vgvdlrpj64l_g98d_dxs5pd40000gp/T/npm.80873/package
```

I was able to successfully update by using the command `npm install -g npm@latest` instead, [as suggested by GitHub user bronzeiii](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11385).

## Cleaning up before re-running `npm install`

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
```

## Final step

`npm install`